# Editing Application Insight Terraform Resource Name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have this code in TF for creating App Insight Resource.
The name for creating the App Insight is being done by our internal names module.
The output of the name for App Insight is of the format -->
(Resource Group Name)-(Your own custom value)-dev-cus-001
Now we have 3 resources for App Insight with 3 custom values defined in the Locals block as shown below:

```
locals {
  application-insights = [
    "masterdata",
    "inboundintegration",
    "intgr-func",
  ]
}


module "names-application-insights" {
  version              = "~> 1.0"
  source               = "My Module URL"
  for_each             = toset(local.application-insights)
  resource_type        = "application-insights"
  resource_location    = var.resource_group_location
  resource_environment = var.resource_group_environment
  resource_name        = format("%s-%s", var.resource_group_name, each.value)
  resource_count       = var.resource_group_count
}


resource "azurerm_application_insights" "default" {
  for_each            = toset(local.application-insights)
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  name                = module.names-application-insights[each.value].results
  application_type    = "web"
}
```

Now i have been asked to remove the custom value "masterdata" from the name of the first App Insight resource :  (rg)-masterdata-dev-cus-001
So how do i remove the "masterdata" value from just one App Insights and ensure the other two App Insights that are created with two Locals : "inboundintegration" & "intgr-func" are not affected
If i remove the first custom value "masterdata" from the Locals block, it will throw error right if i run the code after removing that value from Locals?
How to edit this resource name then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you use for_each to create the application insights. Then the only thing you can do is to remove the custom value `masterdata` from the Locals and it won't affect the other two resources. It means you will only create two application insights with the names "inboundintegration" & "intgr-func".

Comment: What about the third one without "masterdata" custom value? I just want to remove the name "masterdata" from the app insight resource "(Resource Group Name)-masterdata-dev-cus-001".  But i do need to have this resource as well. So i need 3 App Insights, two with the custom names and one without the custom name "masterdata" but the other things will be there excluding the "masterdata" part.

Comment: @Pallab Well, to achieve this purpose, you can use the condition for the name, for example: `name = each.value == "masterdata" ? "{var.resource_group-name}-dev-cus-001" : module.names-application-insights[each.value].results`.

Comment: @Pallab Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?